How to use Spring Boot Eureka Server in Spring Boot >=3.3.0
I use Spring Boot Initializer for creating my services. Currently, I want to create a Eureka Server, but I receive the message 'Eureka Server requires Spring Boot >=3.2.0 and 3.3.0-M1.' However, with the chosen version of 3.3.0, the option to create the project is disabled. Is the project discontinued, or what does this mean?


Yes, they updated the dependencies, and now there is no more dependencie missmatches. Just try again
